# How to compare multiple variables to the same value?

Tags: python

I am using Python and I would like to  have an if statement with many variables in it.

Such as:

```
if A, B, C, and D >= 2:
    print (A, B, C, and D)
```

I realize that this is not the correct syntax and that is exactly the question I am asking — what is the correct Python syntax for this type of an `if` statement?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641089/python-equivalent-of-linq-all-function

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You want to test a condition for [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) the variables:

```py
if all(x >= 2 for x in (A, B, C, D)):
    print(A, B, C, D)
```

This should be helpful if you're testing a *long* list of variables with the same condition.

---

If you needed to check:

```
if A, B, C, or D >= 2:
```

Then you want to test a condition for [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) of the variables:

```py
if any(x >= 2 for x in (A, B, C, D)):
    print(A, B, C, D)
```

Answer (score 20):

Another idea:

```
if min(A, B, C, D) >= 2:
    print A, B, C, D
```

Comment: It works for this particular case, but in general, you can't compare the same condition for multiple variables at once

Comment: `min` means: find the minimum of all the numbers between the parenthesis. If even the minimum is greater or equal than 2, we can conclude that all of the variables are greater or equal than 2

Comment: Oh I get it now! I know what Limbo Peng was saying now! Thanks for the help!

Comment: `min(...)` won't shortcircuit whereas `all(...)` does

Comment: Not so clear but an awesome idea! Solved my problem. Same can be done with `max`, perhaps some other math methods... ;)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when you say that `all(...)` can short circuit?

Comment: @bendl: It stops evaluating as soon as the result is known.

Comment: Is there a situation where that's not preferable?

Answer (score 7):

I'd probably write this as

```
v = A, B, C, D
if all(i >= 2 for i in v):
    print v
```

Comment: Thanks! To clarify the meaning of what  you are telling me... If I had A, B, C, and D. Could I just say v = A, B, C, D (RETURN - can't get the code tag to work) if all(v >= 2): (RETURN) print (v)?

Comment: @TerriMoore: No, because that would be asking if the tuple (A, B, C, D) was greater than or equal to 2, not whether all the values are >= 2.  For technical reasons that won't actually raise an Exception in python 2, it'll just give unexpected results, but it will raise an error (as it should) in python 3.

Comment: I am using python 3. What exactly would the "i in v" thing be looking at?

Comment: @LimboPeng's answer is a little more directly implemented, without the intermediate 'v' variable.

Comment: OK so you recommend Limbo's answer over DSM's?

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
if A >= 2 and B >= 2 and C >= 2 and D >= 2:
    print A, B, C, D
```

For the general case, there isn't a shorter way for indicating that the same condition must be true for all variables - unless you're willing to put the variables in a list, for that take a look at some of the other answers.

Comment: Thanks! I have 10 variables is their anything that takes less typing?

Comment: If you need to test the same condition (>= 2) and all the variables are numbers, @Fred Larson's answer is the shortest solution (albeit a bit hard to understand at a glance)

Comment: If I need to do other conditions would the answer provided by DSM be the best?

Comment: Same thing: it works only if the condition is the same for all variables; otherwise you have to test each variable individually, one by one, as in my answer

Comment: Ya I want them to all be tested against the same condition individually not as a group but I want to put it all into one if statement.

Comment: What I mean as not as a group is not adding them together or anything. I want the if to be: If and only If ALL the variables are less than or greater than 2 do the following.

Comment: Then I'd go with @Limbo Peng's or DSM's answer

Comment: Thanks I think I will go with Limbo Peng's.

Comment: I am a little confused on the parenthesis used in his answer though.

Answer (score 3):

If you have ten variables that you are treating as a group like this, you probably want to make them elements of a list, or values in a dictionary, or attributes of an object.  For example:

```
my_dict = {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3 }

if all(x > 2 for x in my_dict.values()):
    print "They're all more than two!"
```

Comment: No that isn't what I am trying to achieve here. But thanks anyways!

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, passing a list to a function may work.

```
def foo(lst):
    for i in lst:
        if i < 2:
            return
    print lst
```

Comment: Oops! I've just posted the same answer as yours. LOL

Comment: If you could explain what this is doing in more detail I would really help me. Thanks!

Comment: You pass the function a list of numbers.  For each item in the list, check to see if the item is less than 2 - if the item is less than 2, then the function "returns" (or exits) without printing anything.  Continue checking each item in the list.  Once each item has been checked, and no item caused the function to return/exit, we know that ALL items are >= 2, so we can print the list.

Answer (score 1):

Except that she's probably asking for this:

```
if A >= 2 and B >= 2 and C >= 2 and D >= 2:
```