# Python equivalent of LINQ All function?

Tags: python, linq

What is the idiomatic Python way to test if all elements in a collection satisfy a condition? (The [.NET `All()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx) fills this niche nicely in C#.)

There's the obvious loop method:

```
all_match = True
for x in stuff:
    if not test(x):
        all_match = False
        break
```

And a list comprehension could do the trick, but seems wasteful:

```
all_match = len([ False for x in stuff if not test(x) ]) > 0
```

There's got to be something more elegant... What am I missing?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641008/compare-multiple-variables-to-the-same-value-in-if-in-python

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
all_match = all(test(x) for x in stuff)
```

This short-circuits and doesn't require stuff to be a list -- anything iterable will work -- so has several nice features.

There's also the analogous

```
any_match = any(test(x) for x in stuff)
```

Comment: Definitely the way I'd go. However, `all` in Python differs from `Enumerable.All` in that it does not directly take a predicate. (So it's more akin to `Enumerable.Where(predicate).All()`.)