# Why does this while loop not work?

Tags: python, loops

This loop keeps looping even if I enter "no" and when I type "jdlfjap", for example, it continues to loop without a "?".

Does anyone know why this is?

```
def makeContact():
    contactName = input("Name: ")
    contactNumber = input("Number: ")
    dictionaryForContacts[contactName] = contactNumber
def continueMaking():
    while True:
        continueMaking = input("\nWould you like to continue making contacts? ")
        if continueMaking == "Yes" or "yes" or "YES":
            makeContact()
            continue
        elif continueMaking == "No" or "no" or "NO":
            break
        else:    
            print ("?")
            continue
```

Comment: `continueMaking == "No" or "no" or "NO"` doesn't do what you think it does. It doesn't compare `continueMaking` to each of those 3 words.

Comment: Use `lower()` or checkout [`in`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in)

Comment: Rewrite as `if continueMaking in ("Yes", "yes", "YES")` or `if continueMaking.strip().lower() ==  "yes"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare multiple variables to the same value in "if" in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641008/compare-multiple-variables-to-the-same-value-in-if-in-python)

Comment: You can try things in the interactive prompt: `>>> "no" == "Yes" or "yes" or "YES"` gives `'yes'`

Answer (score 2):

The statement `if continueMaking == "Yes" or "yes" or "YES":` is equivalent to `(continueMaking == "Yes") or "yes" or "YES":` which, regardless of the value of `continueMaking` returns the string `"YES"`, which is truthy and thus the `makeContact` call always executes. Case-insensitive string comparisons can be accomplished by `continueMaking.lower() == "yes"`.

Comment: Great answer, but probably should be `continueMaking.strip().lower() == "yes"` to catch trailing spaces.

Comment: Based on [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html), why wouldn't it be evaluated to `continueMaking == true` since `or` has a higher precedence and it would be coerced into a boolean?

Comment: Nope, that statement simplifies to `True if continueMaking == "Yes" else "yes"`.

Answer (score 1):

Overwriting the function `continueMaking` with the variable `continueMaking` adds confusion. Choose a different variable name. Readability counts.