# "or" in a while loop confusion

Tags: python

So I am going back to basics with Python, after a long stint in JS. And I just something out which goes against what I thought it would do.

I have the following code:

```
name = ''
while name != 'your name' or 'your name.':
    print('Please type your name.')
    name = input()
print('Thank you!')
```

However, when I run the script, and input either `'your name'` or `'your name'` the script just keeps looping and doesn't come out of the loop.

I am confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your second condition is just a string `'your name.'`, which is always true. You need to add `name != 'your name.'` to the second condition:

```
while name != 'your name' or name != 'your name.':
```

Comment: Ah yes! Thanks, silly me!

Comment: You could also create a set of valid strings and test for containment: `while name not in {'your name', 'your name.'}:`

Comment: Or you could use `while not name.startswith('your name')`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
while True:
    print('Please type your name.')
    name = input()
    if name.startswith('your name'):
        print('invalid')
    else:
        break

print('Thank you!')
```