# if a or b explanation

Tags: python, syntax

```
a = None

b = 'Test'

if a is None or b is None:
    print('Test')
```

this version is obviously working but:

```
if (a or b) is None:
   print('Test')
```

Expected would be the same result but it evaluates to False, why?

Comment: Because `(a or b) is b`. `(a and b) is None`. It's not clear why you thought the two different things would have the same result.

Comment: why `is b` , what is the full syntax here?
i simply want to shorten the `if a is X or b is X or....`

Comment: @Sentinan that's the point! you cannot "shorten" it like that, what you wrote in the second version is an entirely different thing. A shorter, but truly equivalent expression would be: `if not a or not b:`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare multiple variables to the same value in "if" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641008/compare-multiple-variables-to-the-same-value-in-if-in-python)

Answer (score 6):

In Python, an `or` statement does not just return `True` or `False`, it returns the first of it's arguments that is ["truthy"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39983695/2800876).

In your code, the following happens when evaluating `(a or b) is None`:

1. `None` is falsy, and `a` is `None`, so `a or b` returns `b`.
2. `b` is not `None`.
3. `(a or b) is None` resolves to `False`.

Answer (score 4):

Operator precedence and evaluation rules of boolean expressions work a bit different in Python. This is not doing what you imagine:

```
(a or b) is None
```

The above condition is asking whether the result of evaluating `(a or b)` is `None`, and it will never be `None` with the current values of `a` and `b`; `a or b` will return `'Test'` (the value of `b`), because `a` is `None`. If you want to test if either one of two values is `None`, only the first syntax is valid:

```
a is None or b is None
```

Just to be clear, in Python `x or y` will return the value of the first non-false expression, and `None`, `[]`, `{}`, `''`, `0` and `False` are considered false. If what you want is to shorten the expression a bit, this is equivalent to the first version of your code:

```
if not a or not b:
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be super brief, you can used the following construction:

```
if None in (a, b):
    print('Test')
```

Please note that while this will work in the majority of cases, the expression is not exactly equivalent to `a is None or b is None` but rather `a == None or b == None`. See [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257919/what-is-the-difference-between-is-none-and-none) of why this is not the same thing.