# It's possible use two logical expression in one

Tags: python

I would like to know if it is possible to do something like this in python:

```py
if x and y < 0
```

insted of:

```py
if x < 0 and y < 0
```

In the first case, I see that `x` is taken as a bool instead of int.
Is there any sugar syntax for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There actually is syntax to do this (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58495259/388593)), but you could also do something like

```
if max(x, y) < 0:
```

Comment: why not just `max(x, y) < 0`?

Answer (score 2):

If you love ugly code boy you've come to the right place.

```
if x < 0 > y
```

If you have a lot of variables this one's actually decent.

```
if all(n < 0 for n in [x, y, z])
```

Answer (score 1):

The `all()` builtin function allows you to test a collection of variables against a condition. Not exactly sugar, but it is generally pythonic.

```py
if all(z < 0 for z in (x, y)):
```

Here is a similar SO question, along with the official python docs on this function.

[Compare multiple variables to the same value in "if" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641008/compare-multiple-variables-to-the-same-value-in-if-in-python)

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all

Answer (score 0):

```
all(map(lambda z: z>0, [x,y]))
```

should do it