# Why isn't my while loop ending when it fulfills one of the conditions?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm in the progress of building a basic blackjack game and I've made a while loop that should terminate once either player hand or house hand is greater than 21 but it just keeps looping?

the crazy thing is that I actually did make it work once but I accidentally broke it again while testing another function that I tried to get working (turning the 11 into a 1 if greater than 21) and I can't seem to get it working again?

```
import random

cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]

player_hand = []

house_hand = []

def player_opening_hand():
    for hand in range (0,2):
        player_hand.append(random.choice(cards))
def house_opening_hand():
    for hand in range(0,2):
        house_hand.append(random.choice(cards))
def total_score(hand):
    return sum(hand)
def new_draw(draw):
    draw.append(random.choice(cards))
    # if total_score(draw) > 21 and 11 in draw:
    #     draw[11] = 1
def current_score():
    print(f'Your cards: {player_hand}, total score: {total_score(player_hand)}')
    print(f"computer's first card: {house_hand[0]}")

def final_score():
    print(f'Your cards: {player_hand}, total score: {total_score(player_hand)}')
    print(f"computer's cards: {house_hand}, house total score: {total_score(house_hand)}")


#Intro to the player

begin = input('welcome to pyjack, would you like to start a new game? enter "y" or "n": ')




if begin == 'y':
    # first two cards for both players are dealt,
    player_opening_hand()
    house_opening_hand()
    current_score()
    if total_score(player_hand) == 21:
        print('you won!')
    else:
        while total_score(player_hand) and total_score(house_hand) < 21:
            player_choice = input('Type "y" to get another draw or type "n" to pass: ')
            if player_choice == 'y':
                new_draw(player_hand)
                current_score()
        if total_score(player_hand) > 21:
            final_score()
            print('you went over 21, you lose!')
        elif total_score(player_hand) > total_score(house_hand):
            final_score()
            print('your hand is bigger than the house! you win!')
        elif total_score(player_hand) == 21 and total_score(house_hand) < 21:
            final_score()
            print('Blackjack! you win!')
        else:
            final_score()
            print('you lose!')
```

Comment: what is `while total_score(player_hand) and total_score(house_hand) < 21:` supposed to mean?  Doesn't the bit before the `and` need a comparison to something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare multiple variables to the same value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641008/how-to-compare-multiple-variables-to-the-same-value)

Answer (score 0):

You always have to mention the both conditions using `AND` or `OR` operators.
Here condition is to be:

```
while total_score(player_hand) < 21 and total_score(house_hand) < 21:
```

I hope this will work for you.

Answer (score -1):

```
while total_score(player_hand) and total_score(house_hand) < 21:
```

does not do what you think it does. The correct code is

```
while total_score(player_hand) < 21 and total_score(house_hand) < 21:
```